# Why won't my animation render in mp4 format?

Tags: rendering

I'm new and need help. I'm trying to save a video as an mp4 file and understand that I need to render it to do so. However, when I try to render it as an mp4 file, I'm met with a black and gray checkerboard rather than my animation. I have tried rendering it as other file types and it works. But I need the file to be in mp4. Is there anything that can be done?

Comment: maybe share more specifics of your output settings or attach your blend file

Comment: The checkerboard represents completely transparent imagery. Why that is showing up here could be a dozen things, including normal functionality in some cases with compositing. Please include more detail.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.